# What is the best way to get only certain properties using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, reflection

I am trying to come up with the best way to get only certain properties from a type using reflection.  How can I differentiate the properties from each other?

Let me add this to help clarify my question.

I understand that I can use binding flags or name.  But say I want only a certain four properties.  Would the best way be to create a custom attribute for the ones I want then loop through all of the properties to see if they have that attribute?

Comment: using custom attributes will let you narrow it down faster, because you can check at a slightly higher level, but you still have to hit each property. How tight to the center of a loop is this running, and how often? It may not even be worth optimizing.

Comment: It should only run through them one time when the control is created and right now there aren't that many properties like 10 so I think I'm just going to stay with the custom attributes on 4 of them.  If you have a better idea(is this was on a larger scale) please let me know.

Comment: Actually I was just going to say that the way you're doing it is roughly how I'm doing it on an AOP that I'm working on for myself, to monitor values on certain elements so I can attribute in a couple places and pick up logging to make my life easier (yay internal tools that only work for a few people :\ ) ... and with only having a few properties and only using them when the control is created, the overhead isn't enough to worry about unless you're doing it thousands* of times a second. ~~ *still should be profiled of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, fairly obviously by name, or by type, or by declaring type (e.g. the type or its base class).

Basically if you can describe what you mean by "certain properties" it's just a matter of turning that predicate into code. For example, suppose you only wanted properties beginning with A:

```
var properties = type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("A"));
```

Comment: Sadly this seems like "please write my code for me" rather than a real question. As with all programming questions, "show me the explicit business rules and I'll show you the high level code that you need to turn into machine understandable code"

Comment: @drachenstern I updated the question to be more clear, no need to be a dick.

Comment: @Mike ~ a) You've been around long enough to know how to ask questions. b) Also, I didn't feel I was being a dick. Really I wanted to emphasize @Jon Skeet's comment about "turning predicate into code".

Answer (score 1):

`System.Reflection.BindingFlags` are designed to allow you to filter things like public / private, member / static when reflecting types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Type.GetProperty(string)` to get certain property.